# Wrap around div above while the center div stays in the middle

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I don't know if this is possible with plain CSS:

[image]

I have 2 elements in my app:

- timeline component (blue)
- legend component (green)

The timeline (blue) component should be always centered, the legend (green) component should be aligned to the right side.

The problem, which I'm not able to solve is the following. If there isn't room for both of them, the legend (green) component should be wrapped above timeline (blue) component and the timeline component should stay in the center like in the image bellow:

[image]

Closer I can get is this:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.time-line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.ghost {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}

.legend {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.col-center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col3">
    <div class="ghost"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3 col-center">
    <div class="time-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div class="legend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there is enough space for both components it behaves as it should, but as soon as there isn't enough room for them, the green component wraps bellow blue and also the blue component isn't centered anymore:

[image]

**EDIT:** I can't use media queries, since the timeline (blue) component's width is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.col-center {
  order: 1;
}
```